# Obesity and lifting, is it safe?

Tags: lifting, obesity

Is it safe for obese people to lift weights?

When they do lose their weight however, previously obese people can become phenomenal athletes because of how powerful their organs have had to become.

Comment: You seem to hhave answered your own question ... so what exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 2):

yes,natural functional movements are safe and encouraged for obese people.The only thing to keep in mind for an obese person is that organs are being crushed by their visceral fat, so have to work harder, therefore intensity must be managed to prevent organ trauma.